# JS Fade out (opacity) on scroll - Won't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a simple script which is nicely working for FF and Chrome, but IE is as alsways a Partypooper. Any ideas/suggestions?

HTML

```
<div class="title">
    <p>Change is the law of life.<br />And those who look only to the past or present<br />are certain to miss the future.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.title {
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
top: 230px;
width: 100%;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
var didScroll = false;
var icon = $(".title");
var $window = $(window);
$(window).scroll(function(){
didScroll = true;
});

window.setInterval(function () {
if (didScroll) {
  if (1-$window.scrollTop()/800 > -10) {
      icon.css({opacity: 1-$window.scrollTop()/800});
  }
  didScroll = false;
}
}, 50);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer? [Your code](http://jsfiddle.net/HSg7F/1/) works fine in IE 8.

Comment: Works fine in IE8 + for me to

Comment: Hmm, I tried it in IE9 and the text isn't fading out on scrolling.

Comment: Sorry guys, I tested it again and it works. It's not working on my local machine, but online. Thanks for testing, at least I know it works also for IE8 :)